# Can't get h1 from webpage in PHP

Tags: php

I want in [this](https://www.goudengids.be/bedrijf/Willebroek/L11159413/CNC+Metal/) page to get the name of the company.
What I've tried :

```
<?PHP
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.goudengids.be/bedrijf/Willebroek/L11159413/CNC+Metal/');
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document ->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($document);
$anchorTags = $xPath->evaluate("//div[@class=\"title-logo\"]//h1");
foreach ((array)$anchorTags  as $anchorTag) {
    echo 'name : '.$anchorTag;
}
?>
```

I did something approximatively like this for another website and it worked, but actually the array $anchorTags seems to be empty. Where is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the xpath you're looking for is:

```
//div[contains(@class,'title-logo')]//h1
```

simple `@class` won't do

Comment: This gives the same results as OP's XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast the results from the XPath `evaluate()` method to use in the `foreach()`, you also need to fetch the (I assume) [`nodeValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) to get the actual content of the header tag...

```
foreach ($anchorTags  as $anchorTag) {
    echo 'name : '.$anchorTag->nodeValue;
}
```

will output...

```
name : CNC Metal
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.goudengids.be/bedrijf/Willebroek/L11159413/CNC+Metal/');
$document = new DOMDocument;
@$document->loadHTML($html); // using @ here to suppress a warning

$headings = $document->getElementsByTagName('h1');
foreach ($headings as $node) {
    echo 'name : '.$node->nodeValue;
}
```